# Block recurring event from rendering when other event exists within same time range in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have a datasource which has bookings that that i want to render in fullcalendar eg

```
        {
         title: 'booked',
         groupId: 'unique',
          start: '2020-02-11T08:00:00',
          end: '2020-02-11T10:00:00',
          color: 'blue'
        }
```

However i also have recurring free slots which i want the user to click to eventually make a booking.

```
        {
      title: 'Available',
      daysOfWeek: [ 1,2,3,4],
      startTime: '8:00:00',
      endTime: '10:00:00',
      color: 'red',
      }
```

The aim is that if there is already a booked event in the same time block , the recurring event 'Available' in this slot will not be displayed

How can i achieve this . I am assuming it is with eventRender

I have a jsfiddle here that shows the events competing for the same time block

https://jsfiddle.net/ryan_ramsumair/mqhzs3v2/5/

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered displaying the "available" slots by using [background events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events)? Then you wouldn't really have to worry about this "competing" problem, as the booked event would always be shown on top.

Comment: thanks i will have to resort to this if i cant get a method to do above

Comment: I'd argue it's actually a better solution rather than a last resort. Doing it your way is probably possible but a bit of a hassle in terms of code.

Comment: got it, thanks for the advice